# How can i use a variable of one Higher Order Functions in one generation function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, redux, redux-saga

A need to use `email =  user.email` in `newcomment['comments/'+id] = {id,comment,email,date}`, but i can't use `email = yield user.email` or `yield auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {email =  user.email})` and email is attributed with null in `newcomment`. How i can do this?

```
export function* createComments(action){  
let email = null
try{
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
       email =  user.email
    })
    const id = yield database.ref().child("comments").push().key
    let date = new Date()
    date = yield date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear()
    const newcomment = {}
    const comment = action.comment
    newcomment['comments/'+id] = {
        id,
        comment,
        email,
        date
    }
    database.ref().update(newcomment)
    yield put(ActionCreator.createCommentsSuccess(newcomment))
}catch({message}){
    yield put(ActionCreator.createCommentsFailure(message))
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are interested only in the first time onAuthStateChanged callback is called with an user, you can just simply convert it to a Promise:

```
const user = yield new Promise(resolve => {
  const unsub = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      resolve(user);
      unsub();
    }
  });
});
```